# Is WiX Burn 3.8 failing to set the NTSuitePersonal built-in variable correctly?

Tags: windows, wix, burn, wix3.8

The [WiX](http://wixtoolset.org/) 3.8 Burn [built-in variables](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/bundle/bundle_built_in_variables.html) include some values that describe the operating system edition.  One of these is `NTSuitePersonal`.  This variable is set to zero on an operating system where I would expect it to return as non-zero.  This is preventing me from defining installation conditions for my application.

I wrote a little C# command line app to call [GetVersionEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724451(v=vs.85).aspx) and retrieve an [OSVERSIONINFOEX structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724833(v=vs.85).aspx) with the relevant flags.  I'm running it on two machines.  If I check the first machine, the System Information dialog shows the OS Name as "Microsoft Windows 8.1 Enterprise N".  The command line output is as follows:

```
wSuiteMask & VER_SUITE_PERSONAL: 0x00000100 & 0x00000200 = 0x00000000
wSuiteMask & VER_SUITE_SINGLEUSERTS: 0x00000100 & 0x00000100 = 0x00000100
```

The second machine shows the OS Name as "Microsoft Windows 8.1", and it has the following output:

```
wSuiteMask & VER_SUITE_PERSONAL: 0x00000300 & 0x00000200 = 0x00000200
wSuiteMask & VER_SUITE_SINGLEUSERTS: 0x00000300 & 0x00000100 = 0x00000100
```

Based on this, I would expect the `NTSuitePersonal` WiX Burn built-in variable to be non-zero on the second machine, but it is set to zero on both.  Here is what I see in my log file:

```
Variable: NTSuitePersonal = 0
```

Have I overlooked something, or is this a defect in Burn?

For reference, the full text of my command line app follows:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace OperatingSystemInfoSandbox
{
    class Program
    {
        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        public class OSVERSIONINFOEX
        {
            public int dwOSVersionInfoSize;
            public int dwMajorVersion;
            public int dwMinorVersion;
            public int dwBuildNumber;
            public int dwPlatformId;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 128)]
            public string szCSDVersion;
            public UInt16 wServicePackMajor;
            public UInt16 wServicePackMinor;
            public UInt16 wSuiteMask;
            public byte wProductType;
            public byte wReserved;
            public OSVERSIONINFOEX()
            {
                this.dwOSVersionInfoSize = (int)Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(OSVERSIONINFOEX));
            }
        }

        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern bool GetVersionEx([In, Out] OSVERSIONINFOEX osvi);

        public const UInt16 VER_SUITE_PERSONAL = 0x00000200;
        public const UInt16 VER_SUITE_SINGLEUSERTS = 0x00000100;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var osvi = new OSVERSIONINFOEX();
            GetVersionEx(osvi);
            Console.WriteLine("wSuiteMask & VER_SUITE_PERSONAL: 0x{0:x8} & 0x{1:x8} = 0x{2:x8}",
                osvi.wSuiteMask, VER_SUITE_PERSONAL, osvi.wSuiteMask & VER_SUITE_PERSONAL);
            Console.WriteLine("wSuiteMask & VER_SUITE_SINGLEUSERTS: 0x{0:x8} & 0x{1:x8} = 0x{2:x8}",
                osvi.wSuiteMask, VER_SUITE_SINGLEUSERTS, osvi.wSuiteMask & VER_SUITE_SINGLEUSERTS);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please file a bug. Looks like it doesn't properly check the mask.

Comment: Thanks, Bob!  That is an answer from a position of authority.  :-)  I have submitted [issue 4580](http://wixtoolset.org/issues/4580/).